# TFS Build Definition: prevent copy DLL to drop folder

Tags: tfs, build-process

We use TFS 2012 Build server for our Web Project

Build result is copied into folder _PublishedWebsites of Build drop folder
_PublishedWebsites contains all we need to deploy site later
But all DLL existing in _PublishedWebsites are repeated in the drop folder as well.
So we have in drop folder:

**_PublishedWebsites

Bin**

        WebSiteLibrary1.Dll
        WebSiteLibrary2.Dll
        WebSiteLibrary3.Dll
**logs**
WebSiteLibrary1.Dll
WebSiteLibrary2.Dll
WebSiteLibrary3.Dll

How to configure Build Definition dll be copied only to _PublishedWebsites ?

Answer (score 1):

You must customize the Build Template: or you tweak the final Copy to Drop Destination, but it could be easier to add a Delete files after that Activity, even if it is slower.

Please, check the names.